# Debugging crash in Cordova App

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, bluetooth

I am currently developing a cordova / AngularJS based cross platform app with some third party plugins (mainly Bluetooth) and am looking for a way to debug the native Java code of the app or log crash information.

App is running on KitKat 4.4.4 / Samsung Galaxy S4 via cordova run android --debug command

IDE is currently NetBeans with Cygwin console

The javascript console provides no information as to the crash but is clearly tied to the Bluetooth plugin i am using https://github.com/bcsphere/bluetooth

I have tried using adb logcat command but it seems to just continually print out data for an extended period of time without providing anything particularly useful.

Have a basic grasp of Java so would be interested in finding the Java error causing the crash if possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Enable developer mode in android settings
2. Enable debug by usb
3. Plug your device to the computer by usb
4. Run in the terminal: adb logcat
5. Run the application in your phone, adb logcat will give you the java crash report

To see what you want do this:

```
adb logcat | grep -i "nameofyourapp"
```

It will filter the lines of the log

Comment: Thanks, should have mentioned i was on Windows too, ran it through Git Bash CLI as Cygwin within Netbeans wouldnt have it for some reason. Thanks again