# Cordova app compiles but crashes on run. How to get error report?

Tags: android, cordova, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, crash-reports

I have a Cordova app that compiles with no errors. However, when I lunch the app to my android device it instantly crashes on startup. I am having a hard time debugging when I do not know what the bug is…

**QUESTION: Is there a way to get the error report from this crash?**

I usually use chrome to debug my app but that only works if the app is able to load and run on the device.

Comment: Search how to collect and check "Force Close" via LOGCAT

Comment: @Guilherme P is there a specific article you can recommend?

Comment: See this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32115428/1814840 for instructions on getting the error from logcat

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You requested some article about logcat... I'm putting in the answer section since it is too much information for comments :)

**DOCS**

In case of Android, you can always go to Developer's page.

[HERE](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html) is the Android's page about logcat

If you use android Studio, you can also check this [LINK](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html#systemLogView).

**Capturing**

Basically, you can capture logcat with following command:

```
adb logcat
```

There's a lot of parameters you can add to command which helps you to filter and display the message that you want... This is personal...  I always use the command below to get the message timestamp:

```
adb logcat -v time
```

You can redirect the output to a file and analyze it in a Text Editor.

**Analyzing**

If you app is Crashing, you'll get something like:

```
07-09 08:29:13.474 21144-21144/com.example.khan.abc D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-09 08:29:13.475 21144-21144/com.example.khan.abc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.khan.abc, PID: 21144
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed()' on a null object reference
     at com.example.khan.abc.AudioFragment$1.onClick(AudioFragment.java:125)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
07-09 08:29:15.195 21144-21144/com.example.khan.abc I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21144 SIG: 9
```

This part of the log shows you a lot of information:

- When the issue happened: `07-09 08:29:13.475`

It is important to check when the issue happened... You may find several errors in a log... you must be sure that you are checking the proper messages :)

- Which app crashed: `com.example.khan.abc`

This way, you know which app crashed (to be sure that you are checking the logs about your message)

- Which ERROR: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

A NULL Pointer Exception error

- Detailed info about the error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed()' on a null object reference`

You tried to call method `onBackPressed()` from a `FragmentActivity` object. However, that object was `null` when you did it.

- Stack Trace: Stack Trace shows you the method invocation order... Sometimes, the error happens in the calling method (and not in the called method).

  at com.example.khan.abc.AudioFragment$1.onClick(AudioFragment.java:125)

Error happened in file `com.example.khan.abc.AudioFragment.java`, inside `onClick()` method at line: `125` (stacktrace shows the line that error happened)

It was called by:

```
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
```

Which was called by:

```
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20262)
```

which was called by:

```
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
```

etc....

**Overview**

This was just an overview... Not all logs are simple etc... It is just to share the idea and provide a entry-level information to you...

I hope I could help you someway...
Regards

Answer (score 0):

•   Delete the existing folder of MFP Named as : cordova-plugin-mfp (Older Version of MFP Plugin)

•   Now run this command and installed the latest version of mfp – “ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp@8.0.2018112111”

•   Now recheck the version by navigating to this path and opening Plugin.xml file inside the mfp folder : D:*******8\FMB_1128_MFP8\plugins\cordova-plugin-mfp\plugins.xml

•   You will see the version like this : version="8.0.2018112111" here 8.0 Stands for MFP-8 : 2018: Year of Update: 11:Month of update

By doing these following steps, you will fix the crash issue of the app over android-p version –‘9’